# Raw pointers for C interop

Tags: c, pointers, rust

To utilise some Rust code in Python I believe it needs to be passed through a C interface, to do this for the interface I am using ([CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)), I believe I need to return a considerable number of raw pointers (it notes `The ctype is usually some constant string describing the C type. It must be a pointer or array type.`). I'm having difficulty with this.

It's a little difficult to succinctly explain, so upfront, here's a playground of the problem: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=d541592aa6011e5d67c279680f855743

I have a function which returns complex type:

```rust
fn test_function() -> CArray<CArray<SymbolPixels>> {
    // Just some test data
    let temp: Vec<Vec<(Vec<u8>, Bound<usize>)>> = vec![
        vec![(vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7],Bound::new())],
        vec![(vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7],Bound::new()),(vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7],Bound::new()),(vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7],Bound::new())]
    ];
    CArray::new(temp.into_iter().map(|sl| {
        CArray::new(sl.into_iter().map(|(s, b)| SymbolPixels { 
            pixels: &CArray::new(s), 
            bound: &ReturnBound::new(b)
        }).collect::<Vec<SymbolPixels>>())
    }).collect::<Vec<CArray<SymbolPixels>>>())
}


#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Bound<T: Ord + Copy> {
    pub min: Point<T>,
    pub max: Point<T>,
}
// This impl is just for easy testing here
impl Bound<usize> {
    fn new() -> Bound<usize> {
        Bound { min: Point { x:1, y:2 }, max: Point { x:5, y:9 } }
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct CArray<T> {
    pub ptr: *const T,
    pub size: usize,
}
impl<T> CArray<T> {
    pub fn new(v: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        let (ptr,size,_) = v.into_raw_parts();
        CArray {
            ptr: ptr,
            size: size,
        }
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct SymbolPixels {
    pub pixels: *const CArray<u8>,
    pub bound: *const ReturnBound
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ReturnBound {
    pub min: *const Point<u32>,
    pub max: *const Point<u32>,
}
impl ReturnBound {
    pub fn new(b: Bound<usize>) -> Self {
        ReturnBound { 
            min: &Point { x: b.min.x as u32, y: b.min.y as u32 },
            max: &Point { x: b.max.x as u32, y: b.max.y as u32 }
        }
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Point<T: Ord> {
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
}
```

and currently attempting to read the return result:

```rust
fn main() {
    let segment = test_function();
    unsafe {
        println!("segment: {:.?}",segment);
        let lines = std::slice::from_raw_parts(segment.ptr, segment.size);
        println!("lines: {:.?}",lines);
        for line in lines.iter() {
            let symbols = std::slice::from_raw_parts(line.ptr, line.size);
            for s in symbols.iter() {
                println!("{:.?}",*s.bound);
                // THE PROBLEM:
                // The below line doesn't work
                println!("{:.?}",*(s.bound).min);
                // (Rust throws an error and it simply crashes the Python program when access is attempted)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error (sometimes the playground simply crashes):

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0615]: attempted to take value of method `min` on type `*const ReturnBound`
  --> src/main.rs:16:45
   |
16 |                 println!("{:.?}",*(s.bound).min);
   |                                             ^^^ method, not a field
   |
help: use parentheses to call the method
   |
16 |                 println!("{:.?}",*(s.bound).min(_));
   |                                                ^^^

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0615`.
error: could not compile `playground`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I am fairly sure this is a result of my misuse of pointers here, I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: `std::slice::from_raw_parts` doesn't look like C code to me

Comment: For the compiler error try `println!("{:.?}",(*s.bound).min);` instead. Haven't checked for further errors.

Comment: @HHK So that has fixed it, very small issue lol. Post answer I'll mark it right (got few issues my end, but think this at least fixes this bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler error message is misleading. Try `println!("{:.?}",(*s.bound).min);` instead.

Comment: So, this fixes the immediate problem but exposes a more significant underlying problem, I'll make a new question for it and post a link in a bit (`(*(*s.bound).min)` when using `#[no_mangle] pub extern "C" fn test_function()...` leads to seg errors, since I missed that bit out of this question I'll make new question for it)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66586616/rust-c-interop-segmentation-fault-slash-status-access-violation